# Android studio - Emulator not working on Mac High Sierra

Tags: android-studio

I've tried reinstalling HAMX (latest version) on my mac high sierra but still fail to get the emulator on android studio working. I get this message.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra1vo.jpg
I saw on other questions to go to security and privacy and allow the download but nothing comes up for me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried updating Android Studio and it worked